# Cropping an image in any shape

Tags: c#

Crop an image by mouse draging shape. not in rectangle shape.
If I am click and drag the mouse in a particular shape crop image in that shape

Comment: I think he wants a free hand cropping. Mouse Press on X,Y and drag to X2,Y2 and crop on that. But then again, I can be wrong the question is hard to understand.

Comment: I think he wants something like the lassoo tool in photoshop, rather than a simple X,Y X2,Y2 - could be wrong though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your final image can obviously only be a rectangle and have a height and width.

You would need to keep coordinates of the shape you "draw/drag" and then somehow use this as a mask to set the pixels outside this area to a specific "empty/background" colour or transparent if the image type supports it.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:

```
Image img = Imager.Crop(sourceImage, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
```

http://imager.codeplex.com/

instead of `new Rectangle` you do something else